# approval request sent multiplied

Tags: trigger, approval-process

i write this trigger to auto submission approval request:

```
  trigger OpportunitySubmitForOrderListApproval on Opportunity (after update) {
for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++) {
    if ((Trigger.old[i].Integration_fees__c == 0  &&  Trigger.old[i].Integration_waived__c== True)  && (Trigger.new[i].Integration_fees__c==0  &&  Trigger.new[i].Integration_waived__c== True)) {
        // create the new approval request to submit
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        req.setComments('Submitted for approval. Please approve.');
        req.setObjectId(Trigger.new[i].Id);
        // submit the approval request for processing
        Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req);
        // display if the reqeust was successful
        System.debug('Submitted for approval successfully: '+result.isSuccess());
}
}
}
```

i also create an approval procces with this entry criteria:

```
(Opportunity: Integration fees EQUALS 0) AND (Opportunity: Integration waived EQUALS True).
```

their automaitcally 2 approval request that send to the approver. maybe i need to delete on of the two? thank you very much!

Comment: Are you saying you have a trigger that creates the approval request and a regular approval process also? You definitely don't want to have both!

Comment: i think that what i did is trigger who auto submitted the approval proccess?
that was my intent @crmprogdev

Comment: Yes, you're creating a submission, but you're not setting the `submitterId`. You're also not putting a value to `setProcessDefinitionNameOrId`. I don't see any recursion protection, so if there's any workflow that occurs after your trigger fires, it gets called again. That would cause a 2nd group of Approval processes to be submitted.

Comment: @crmprogdev so what i need to do for fix the problem?
Thank you very for helping me.

Comment: First, check your debug logs to see if your trigger runs twice when it's called. If you have a test class for it, that would readily show when running the test class. If that's happening, you'll need to use a Static Boolean from Helper Class as shown in my answer to this question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/117339/issue-with-apex-trigger-oldmap-oldmap-is-giving-new-value-of-the-fieldstage-i/117362#117362

Comment: @crmprogdev i dont know how but the debug logs is empty ,maybe because i work in the sandbox, i dont have test class.  
i dont why i have this problem, i work by this tutorial http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/01/04/automating-salesforce-approval-processes-with-apex-triggers/